# How to make a java executable jar file invoke command line?

Tags: java, command-line-interface, executable-jar

I have the following simple program:

```
package meep;

import java.util.Scanner;   

public class EnterString
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String string1;

    System.out.println("Enter a string");

string1 = in.nextLine();

in.close();

System.out.println("Here is what you entered: " + string1);
  }
}
```

What I want to do is make it a runnable jar file that will run this program on the command line (I already know how to make a runnable jar file).

In other words, I want to make a runnable jar file such that opening the file will have the same effect as if I were to type `java EnterString` in the command line.

Also, I'm using Windows, but could I make it platform-independent (i.e., it will invoke the command line on a Mac or Linux system)?

Comment: For windows you can do this, create a .bat file in that `TITLE ApplicationTitle
cd %CD%
java -jar app.jar` 
This bat file should be in the place where you app.jar exist.

Comment: @Pasupathi Is that a batch file that runs command prompt and opens the jar file? I have tried something similar.

My two goals are:

1) Make it an executable file that does not depend on the system (i.e., someone else could download it onto their own computer regardless of directory they put it in.

2) Hopefully make it platform independent so it would work if downloaded to Windows, Mac, or Linux.

Comment: If you create a bat file with my commands, on double clicking it, it'll open a command prompt and start the java application. If it is fine for you, I'll look into for the same in other OS also.

Comment: Okay, so it won't be dependent on the file location of the jar file? I would prefer if there is a way to make it platform-independent, but I suppose having a separate one for Windows, Mac, and Linux would be okay.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows;

```
cd /applicationpath
java -jar app.jar
```

Save it as .bat file - double click will open the application

For Linux;

```
cd /applicationpath
java -jar app.jar
```

Save it as .sh file

For MAC;

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/applicationpath"
java -jar app.jar
```

Save it as .sh file

`chmod 777 <.sh file path>` will run the application.

set .sh file to run on terminal, so double click will start the application.

I haven't tested Linux and MAC, if any mistake, somebody please update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I suppose that meets my multi-platform goal at least, so I appreciate it. I think I could make due by putting it in a zip file which could then unzip the jar program and the batch file into the same folder. That way the batch file could run it without having to find it in another directory.

Comment: Ya you can do that. Having everything in same directory will help. If you want you can create a short cut and have it anywhere irrespective of application directory.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.  This line allows you to run a command on a Terminal.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Your terminal command here")
```

Comment: Well, unfortunately that doesn't solve my dilemma because I would have to already be running the program for it to run that code. If I make the code I currently have into a jar file it doesn't do anything when I run (I'm not sure how to make it do anything, but I want it to run the program in command line).